# Load a variable range into an array

Tags: excel, vba

I want to store a range of variable size in an one-dimensional array. The range starts at A2 and goes to the last row of the same column. My approach looks like that. It's flawed.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Range_to_Array()

Dim i, j, k As Integer
Dim arr1(), arr2(), arr3(), arr4() As Variant

    With Worksheets("table1")

        arr1() = .Cells(.Range("A2"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next way. `Application.Transpose` transforms a 2D array with a column in a 1D type. No iteration needed:

```
Sub Array1DFromColumnRange()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr
 
 Set ws = Worksheets("table1")
 lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
 arr = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("A2:A" & lastR).Value)
    Debug.Print Join(arr, "|") 'just to visually see the result in Immediate Window (Ctrl + G)...
End Sub
```

The returned 1D array is 1 based, as the 2D array directly extracted from a range. To transform it in zero based type, can be done without iteration, too:

```
    'change the array type to be zero based:
    ReDim Preserve arr(0 To UBound(arr) - 1)
    Debug.Print LBound(arr)
    Debug.Print Join(arr, "|")
```

Comment: Very nice use of Transpose.

Comment: Perfect. I'm just wondering why the array generated this way doesn't start with 0?

Comment: @D3merzel A 2D array extracted from a row is 1 based. The 1D resulted array is 1 based, too. If you need a zero based array I can show you how to convert ir

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks for the explanation. It's good the way it is.

Comment: @D3merzel Even if no required in your specific case, maybe it is good to know how the returned such array can be transformed in a zero based one, **without iteration**. So, I edited the above answer and also added a piece of code showing how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your Range-Definition is wrong.

`Cells` expect 2 parameters (row and column) to address one cell. This is not what you want, and even if, your parameters would be wrong.

What you need in your case is `Range`.

Now `Range` can be called either with one or two parameters.
If you call it with one parameter, this defines the whole range.
Examples: `Range("A1")` or `Range("B2:C5")` or `Range("B:B")`
Whats often used in VBA is something like `Range("A1:A" & lastRow)`

If you call it with two parameters, those two parameters define the first and last cell of the range.
Examples: `Range(Range("A1"), Range("C10"))` or `Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(10, 3))`

I would advice to define an intermediate variable to save the Range - makes it much easier to debug. Also the row number of the last cell should go into an intermediate variable.

In your case you could use one of the following

```
Dim r As Range, lastRow As Long
' Get the last row in use (usually its better to go up from the end of the sheet)
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' 2 parameters
Set r = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, lastRow)) 
' 1 Parameter, last row is concatenated to the range definition
Set r = .Range("A2:A" & lastRow)  
' Use Resize 
Set r = .Range("A2").Resize(lastRow-1, 1)   ' -1 because you start at row 2

arr1 = r.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead.

```
Sub Range_to_Array()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim arr1() As Variant, arr2() As Variant, arr3() As Variant, arr4() As Variant
Dim myRange As Range
    With Worksheets("table1")
        arr1 = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Value

    End With
    Debug.Print arr1(1, 1)
End Sub
```

Also please note that in order to properly declare variables, you need to specify data type for each variable separately.

```
Dim i, j, k As Integer
```

actually means

```
Dim i As Variant, j As Variant, k As Integer
```